# height в процентах от div'a

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, мальчики и девочки!

Сначала небольшое введение:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, div {
    padding:1%;
}
body {
    background-color:red;
}
div.div1 {
    height:50%;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
div.div2 {
    float:left;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
div.div3 {
    float:left;
    height:40%;
    background-color:grey;
}
img.img1 {
    float:left;
    height:96%;
    background-color:black;
    width:100px
}
img.img2 {
    float:left;
    height:50%;
    width:100px;
    background-color:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:red;">
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <img src="" class="img1" />
    </div>
    <img src="" class="img2" />
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/BOPOH/beMrx/embedded/result/)

Если коротко: есть главный div, от которого должны рассчитываться остальные значения в процентах. При этом данный div по высоте не должен быть меньше определенного значения.
Написали, сделали, проверяем:

1. Мозила - все работает
2. Опера - значения рассчитываются правильно, но экран почему-то перерисовывается только если обновить страницу. При изменении ширины окна делает почти то, что надо (обновив экран видим, что было все-таки немного не то), но как-то скачками (ведешь - резко больше чем надо и сразу же норма). При изменении высоты окна - ведет себя как-то непредсказуемо: не увеличивает, уменьшает резко и скачками (т.е. до определенного момента не уменьшает, потом резкое уменьшение).
3. IE 9 - все работает
4. IE 8, Safari - появляются проблемы - div'ы ведут себя так как должны, а вот img ведет себя странно - насколько понял рассчитывает значения не от главного div'a, а от body, т.е. div'ы в один прекрасный момент перестают уменьшаться, а вот img продолжает успешно этим заниматься...

Решение (?):

У главного div'a ставим position:static. Появляются другие проблемы:

IE8, Opera, Safari, Мозила - расчет ведется от body, т.е. если у него height меньше min-height главного div'a, то соответственно и остальные элементы будут иметь далеко не ту высоту, которая нужна.
В реальном проекте содержимое главного div'a полностью указано в процентах, т.е. все элементы сохраняют свое положение друг относительно друга, таким образом внешний вид сохраняется таким как надо... Ну или почти... min-height главного div'a никак не учитывается, а это не есть то, что требуется...

Какие могут быть причины такого странного поведения Safari в первом случае и почему игнорируется min-height во втором? Причем как игнорируется - только если надо рассчитать значения height внутренних элементов, сам же div сохраняет свой height равным min-height.

Comment: Писать style для каждого элемента без CSS плохая привычка. Сложнее воспринимать структуру тегов. И лучше сразу приводите ссылку на jsfiddle.net. Многим просто не хочется вбивать все это самим, гораздо проще попробовать изменить что-то в уже работающей реализации.

Comment: Про CSS - делал для примера, поэтому решил не выносить в style. А вот про совет - спасибо, учту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил код в Firefox, IE9&8, Opera. Проблема воспроизводится только в опере и то, только, наверное, из-за особенностей алгоритма перерисовки страницы в окне. Сафари нет, не могу проверить. Ошибка тут и не ошибка совсем. На мой взгляд все везде работает. Проверка поведения сайта при изменении окна браузера это уже перфекционизм. С этим проблем нет нигде, кроме оперы. Но и там проблема есть, только если менять высоту окна. Если менять размер окна за нижний правый угол, то перерисовка происходит нормально.

Добавлено.
Поставил себе Сафари. Попробовал там и понял вашу проблему. В рамках вашего вопроса я нашел решение. Но, если у вас в итоге будут другие исходные данные или появятся еще условия мое решение не будет работать. 
Указать в блоке div ширину, а img внутри него сделать position:absolute.

```
div.div2 {
    float:left;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
}
    img.img1 {
    background-color:black;
    width:100px;
    height:43%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что float в img не нужен. Может там другая была мысль?

Второй вариант.

```
div.div2 {
    float:left;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
    img.img1 {
    background-color:black;
    width:100px;
    height:96%;
    min-height:96px;
}
```

Здесь мы делаем предположение, что блок div1 всегда будет 200px. Поэтому мы можем сделать ограничение в 96px (подобрал), чтобы img1 не уменьшался меньше этого значения. Ведь блок div2 тоже зависит от div1, значит 50% от 200px будет 100px (ну плюс минут там на всякие бордеры и паддинги).

Привожу только второй пример: [cssdesk.com](http://cssdesk.com/SQEG5).

Comment: Про IE8 я немного сгрешил: div'ы там считаются нормально, но вот только от body, а требуется от первого div'a, так что это тоже косяк, т.к. он (первый div держит свой min-height)...
Лично меня интересует - как быть для сафари? Ошибка скорее всего там (может и не в самой сафари, а в том, как для нее надо это реализовывать, а именно это я и хотел узнать).

А про проверку - требования не мои, я их только реализую...

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Так я тоже реализовывал, но тут как раз появляется то, о чем вы говорили: в проекте используются различные стили для портретной и ландшафтной ориентации. Для портретной для первого div'a, например, min-height: 480px, для ландшафтной - min-height: 320px, причем задается это даже не стилями, а jQuery.mobile - он перебивает все стили. При данных условиях (и при заданном min-height у картинки для каждой ориентации) возникает уже другой глюк - у jQuery - он неправильно рассчитывает ориентацию страницы! А точнее, например, при width:333 height:332 - он говорит, что это портретная ориентация!!!

Comment: Я так понимаю, что проблема в этом:

    $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation = get_orientation = function() {
        var elem = document.documentElement;
        return elem && elem.clientWidth / elem.clientHeight < 1.1 ? "portrait" : "landscape";
    };)

И все бы ничего, но при таком раскладе изменение ориентации в CSS и в jQuery происходит неодновременно, а следовательно опять проявляется тот баг, когда картинка меньше того, что было задумано, и появляется ненужное пустое пространство...

Comment: Ну как я понимаю, вы пробовали второй мой вариант, где размеры четко заданы в пикселях. А что получается, когда размер задан в % как в первом моем примере?

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгое отсутствие, уже точно не помню, какие косяки были во втором варианте, но он тоже не помогал. Мы вроде остановились на том, что убрали min-height - т.е. все div'ы продолжают уменьшаться вместе с картинкой и проблема не заметна.

Ваш ответ все равно приму - вы единственный кто попытался помочь)